# Android compressing and sending image via tcp

Tags: c#, java, android, tcp, camera

I am trying to capture an preview image from camera and then sending it to my computer over wifi.

The process is following:

On my phone: Start camera preview, then compress and send it over tcp connection.
On my computer: Receive compressed data and save photo.

I am using this code on mobile:

```
try {           
    ByteArrayOutputStream outstr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
    YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), size.width, size.height, null);
    image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 100, outstr);

    out.writeBytes("DATA|" + outstr.size() + "\n");
    out.flush();
    out.write(outstr.toByteArray());
    out.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        t.append("ER: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Where out is `DataOutputStream` created in `onCreate` method:

```
tcp = new Socket("192.168.0.12", 6996);         
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tcp.getInputStream()));
out = new DataOutputStream(tcp.getOutputStream());
```

Then using this code on my computer:

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    string line = sr.ReadLine();

    if(line.StartsWith("DATA"))
    {
        piccount++;
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(5));
        Console.WriteLine("PHOTO, SIZE: " + size + ", #: " + piccount);
        byte[] data = new byte[size];

        client.GetStream().Read(data, 0, size);

        FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create("C:/Users/M/photo"+piccount+".jpeg"); 
        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

The problem is, som of transmitted pictures are OK, but some of them are corrupted. Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line `client.GetStream().Read(data, 0, size);` . `Stream.Read` doesn't ensure that it will read exactly `size` bytes. You should check its return value and continue to read till all bytes are read.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx

> **Return Value**
>
> The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.

If your intension is to read the whole stream you can use this code:

```
using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create("C:/Users/M/photo" + piccount + ".jpeg"))
{
    client.GetStream().CopyTo(fs);
}
```

Comment: Well, I can't copy whole stream, because I am sending photos repeatedly with the header line DATA|lenght. I implemented this:                  `int i = client.GetStream().Read(data, 0, size);

                        while (i < size)
                        {
                            i = i + client.GetStream().Read(data, i, size - i);
                        }`                        
But it still does not work.